# Validation on Dependent Field in Standard Page

Tags: validation, page-layout, validation-rule, standardlayout

How would I go implement validation on a standard salesforce page?

The validation rules are:

I have the following:

```
1) Attachment - Checkbox (default checked) 
2) URL - Textbox
```

If the Attachment is uncecked then URL is required
If the Attachment is checked then URL should be Readonly/disabled

Comment: `If the Attachment is checked then URL should be Readonly/disabled` this is bit confusing..

Comment: meaning that user can either check the checkbox which is by default and leave it as it is or user can enter the valid URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just go to setup> create > object> your object and create new validation rule

```
if(Attachment == FALSE && URL == null, true, false)
```

It will give error if attachment is uncheck and URL is null.

for second part I don't think it will be natively possible.But you can use validation rule for same something like `if(Attachment == FALSE && URL != null, true, false)` then display error meessage  `please clear URL` . This will solve both problem

Comment: i don't understand >> `for second thing make URL dependent field based on attachment check-box. This will solve both problem` what do you mean by URL dependent field based? can you elaborate little bit more on that

Comment: okay got it but I don't see the `URL__C` in Field Dependency, so I have click on new dependency -> Controlling Field is my attachment and Dependent Field -> I do not see the ur__c ? what might be the issue?

Comment: @NickKahn Please check updated answer.

Comment: Nope did not work, if i add your updated condition `if(Attachment == FALSE && URL != null, true, false)` then i can save my record with unchecking the attachment and not entering anything in the URL field

Comment: this validations works `if(Attachment == FALSE && URL == null, true, false)` but only problem with that is, i can have both attachment checked and enter url but in my case i should only be have one or the other meaning either Attachment checked or enter URL but not BOTH

Comment: @NickKahn you need to create two separate validations(easy to maintain). or combine both conditions