# Disabling Validation rules?

Tags: apex, validation, validation-rule

I'm not sure disabling validation rule is the only way out for this particular scenario but you guys can chime-in ideas how to approach this particular issue.

I have the following [validation rules](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/121078/validation-on-dependent-field-in-standard-page) on my custom__c object

```
if(Attachment__c == FALSE && URL == null, true, false)
```

and a Trigger on before insert and after delete on the same custom__c object

```
  ...........
  ...........
  Attachment__c = false;
  update mycustomobject;
```

when I try to delete the row I'm getting this error:

execution of AfterDelete

> caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row
>   0 with id xxxxx; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION,
>   Attachment is unchecked and URL is empty: []

I know exactly why I'm getting this error because its firing the validation-rule that i have place in but I'm not sure what is best practice to deal with this type of situation?

Anybody?

Comment: It looks like you posted a bunch of questions in regard to the same issue http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/121087/validate-that-a-url-begins-with

Comment: i have had two question regards to the formula and both are different

Comment: they look for me very similar and you are asking here how to bypass the validation. Validation rules are used to prevent any type of changes you don't want to occur, so I belive you'd want to have validation rule adjusted rather than allowing incorrect data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is the only thing that can set Attachment__c to false, you should be able to change your validation rule in include criteria for

```
NOT(ISCHANGED(Attachment__c))
```

From your last post, it would become

```
AND(Attachment__c == false,
NOT(ISCHANGED(Attachment__c)),
NOT(ISBLANK(UR__c)),
NOT(BEGINS(URL__c, "https://")),
NOT(BEGINS(URL__c, "http://")))
```

This would allow your code to set Attachment to false but would not let anyone else edit the record after until the URL field met your requirements.

Otherwise this blog walks through a more generic way for solving this problem:
http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2011/11/bypass-validation-rules-from-apex.html

Comment: Thanks for the link and its dated back to 2011 and I guess nothing much improved since then... I will go first with your approach because its very simple and only minor change but I could not able to work and my validation rules is like this `if(Attachment__c == FALSE && URL == null, true, false)` and try to add ISCHANGED but does not work.

Comment: AND(Attachment__c == false,
    NOT(ISCHANGED(Attachment__c)),
    ISBLANK(URL__c))    try that